# change textview value when alarm generated

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have two classes LCDashBoard2.java and AlarmReceiver.java.I am setting the alarm in 
LCDashBoard2.java and receiving it into AlarmReceiver.java.
        it will cause to show the toast message in AlarmReceiver class in onReceive method.I have one textview with id textViewBadge in LCDashBoard2.java.Now what i want to do is to change the value of textview when alarm is generated.

```
        public class LCDashBoard2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textViewBadge;
            Button idBtnMedicineCabinet;
            private Timer timer = new Timer();
            private TimerTask timerTask;

            TimePicker myTimePicker;
            Button buttonstartSetDialog;
            TextView textAlarmPrompt;
            final static int RQS_1 = 1;

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

            int count=0;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_lcdash_board2);

                textViewBadge=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBadge);
                idBtnMedicineCabinet=(Button)findViewById(R.id.idBtnMedicineCabinet);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);


                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            }

        }

 and my AlarmReceiver.java class is here

public class AlarmReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received in AlarmReceiver!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the textview global as:

```
public static TextView textViewBadge;
```

and in your reciever, after alarm rings:

```
LCDashBoard2.textViewBadge.setText("YOUR TEXT");
```

Comment: my application crashes after using this can you have solution to avoid this

Comment: can you tell at which line it is crashing? Have you taken the reference of textview?

Comment: how to take the reference of textview?

Comment: yes i did it in LCDashBoard.java class i have mentioned this in my question

Comment: not showing any error just gives message that unfortunatly stopped

Comment: yes dear, it shows the error in the logcat once it crashes. we can not help you unless and untill we know the error..

Comment: i am going to check your code in once again and will provide logcat to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your LCDashBoard2 class then call it from your AlarmReceiver onReceive.

In that function textViewBadge.

**Edit:**

In your LCDashBoard2 add the following function:

```
public static void changeText(String args){
    textViewBadge.setText(args);
}
```

In your onReceive just call that function:

```
LCDashBoard2.changeText("Your New Text");
```

Comment: There's no way your app crashes without showing an error in the logcat.

Comment: i am going to check your code in once again and will provide logcat to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Make the textView a global variable. Then use the .setText() method to change the text shown in the UI when necessary.